# How to remove nul characters (\0) from string in Java

Tags: java

I understand that this code in C# is trying to remove `nul` characters (`\0`) from a string.

```
string.Join("", mText.Split(new string[] { "\0" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

Is there any way to do that efficiently in Java?

Comment: ScaryWombat This string is retrieved from a smart card. Is there any chance `null` might be included?

Comment: not sure why this question was downvoted. The upvotes on its answer clearly shows that this question is very relevant.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can write:

```
mText.replace("\0", "");
```

Comment: I get the error message "Illegal escape: '\0'" when I try that. Is this new? I'm using Android so perhaps that is the reason.

Comment: @TobiasReich: So strange! The spec seems clear about this -- see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7 -- so I wouldn't expect any variation between implementations. But maybe try `\u0000` instead?

Comment: Interesting but yes, the \u0000 seems to work. Not sure what's the difference but that does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8+ you could use [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) and a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) like

```
String str = "abc\0def";
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("");
Stream.of(str.split("\0")).forEach(joiner::add);
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(joiner);
```

Output is

```
abc
abcdef
```

Comment: We are using Android so Java 8 is not available here.

Comment: @SandahAung Have they moved up to Java 7 yet?

Comment: They have. And they are also moving to Java 8 with future releases of Android using OpenJDK.