# Remove null character (\x00) in between buffer of byte array : Qt

Tags: c++, qt, buffer, qbytearray, null-character

I am using [`readAll()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll) method of [`QSerialPort`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) class to read data from the virtual COM port.

I am getting two response from my hardware board.
1. Acknowledgement `("10")` string
2. Query Data `(";1395994881;1.0.0")` string data
as a `QByteArray : 10\x00;1395994881;1.0.0`

I want to remove `\x00` character from my `QByteArray`.

Whenever I am trying to perform any operation on my QByteArray, I will perform on first part of the `QByteArray` and that is ``10 . Remaining part is skipped that is `;1395994881;1.0.0`.

Please guide me if there is any way to remove this `\x00` character from `QByteArray`.

**Code**
`QByteArray data = serial.readAll();  //("10\x00;1395994881;1.0.0");`

1. Try out:
   `QList<QByteArray> list = data.split('\x00');
   qDebug()<<list;  // 10`
2. Try out:
   `qDebug()<<data.remove(2, 1); //10`
3. Try out:
   `qDebug()<<QString(data); //10`
4. Try out:
   `qDebug()<<data.replace('\x00', ""); //10`
5. Try out: 
   `Used Loop to go byte by byte, but same result`

I want resulted string as a single string or split, no matter. But need full string something like `10;1395994881;1.0.0` or `10` and `;1395994881;1.0.0`.

I have also referred below `Stack Overflow` questions.
1. [`QByteArray to QString`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131127/qbytearray-to-qstring)
2. [`Remove null from string:Java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491851/how-to-remove-nul-characters-0-from-string-in-java)
3. [`Code Project`](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1064388/How-to-remove-NULL-byte-from-String-in-Cplusplus-Q)

**EDIT**

```
//Function to read data from serial port  
void ComPortThread::readData()
{
    if(m_isComPortOpen) {
        //Receive data from serial port
        m_serial->waitForReadyRead(500); //Wait 0.5 sec
        QByteArray data = m_serial->readAll();
        if(!data.isEmpty()) {
            qDebug()<<"Data: "<<data;  //10\x00;1395994881;1.0.0
            //TODO: Separate out two responce like "10" and ";1395994881;1.0.0"
            //Problem : Unable to split data into two parts.
            emit readyToRead(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please post [mcve]. Init the `data` with the bytes you got from the serial (instead of `serial.readAll()`), so we could compile the code, run a program and reproduce the issues you described above.

Comment: My hardware board writes the data on virtual com port(like COM3) and From my Qt App, I am reading that data using `readAll()` method of `QSerialPort` class. When I print `data` using `qDebug()` its display as expected with `\x00` character.

Comment: If it is displayed like `\00` then it is not the `\x00` character, it is three chars `\  0 0`.

Comment: I believe these are two strings combined: `10\x00;1395994881;1.0.0`. As byte array stores '\0'-terminted strings, writing `QByteArray ba("10\x00;1395994881;1.0.0");` will give you just '10'. I don't know how did you create a byte array you mentioned.

Comment: @vahancho I dint create `QByteArray`, I just read data from serial port. Please refer `EDIT` section for more idea.

Comment: Again, it is your work to provide [mcve] if you wish us to help you. The memory dump of the array would be helpful too.

Comment: @S.M. U cant create that `QByteArray` grammatically, and How can I provide my hardware board o/p to you directly. I have also provide my code snippet, and my findings too.

Comment: If the various methods you've tried (`remove(2, 1)` etc.) don't work as expected, then can I suggest that the contents of the `QByteArray` are *not* what you think they are.  Also, using [`QIODevice::readyRead`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) the way you do is probably not reliable -- the signal will be emitted as soon as `Qt` notices data is available so there's no guarantee that *all* of the response is available from the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QByteArray` returned by the serial port is created from raw data and does not behave like a character string. In order to process the full array you can use the STL style iterator which is robust to the included `NULL` characters. For more info about `fromRawData` arrays, please carefuly  read the [detailed description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#details) in the documentation.

Here's a dirty example showing how you can fix your string:

```
const char mydata[] = {
    '1', '0', 0x00, ';', '1', '3', '9', '5', '9', '9', '4', '8', '8', '1', ';', '1', '.', '0', '.', '0'
};
QByteArray data = QByteArray::fromRawData(mydata, sizeof(mydata));
qDebug() << data; // "10\x00;1395994881;1.0.0"

char fixed[255];
int index = 0;
QByteArray::iterator iter = data.begin();
while(iter != data.end())
{
    QChar c = *iter;
    if (c != '\0') fixed[index++] = c.toLatin1();
    iter++;
}
fixed[index] = '\0';

qDebug() << fixed; // 10;1395994881;1.0.0
```